# Can the graphene's conductivity be explained using only orbitals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, conductors, electronic-band-theory, graphene, nanoscience

I am trying to find a 'easier' or more 'intuitive' way to calculate the conductivity of graphene. I want do this by using atomic or molecular orbitals. Anyone have a clue about how this can be done? Any paper or book will be appreciate.

Comment: AC or DC conductivity?

Comment: @Gilbert Any of then

Answer (score 0):

Start with the tight binding method, which is essentially the coupling of atomic orbitals, to calculate the band structure. Then use Fermi’s Golden Rule to compute the transition rate under light excitation, which you can then relate to the optical conductivity.

Comment: what do you mean with 'optical conductivity'?

Comment: @Ivanovitch AC conductivity due to interband absorption.